# ZF2 uncaught exception on concurrent emails exceeds limit with SMTP server

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework2

ZF2 throws uncaught exception when i am trying to send multiple mail at the same time,
using SMTP server.

After sending 5 emails it throws an exception:

> Uncaught exception: "Could not read from host" from
>   Zend\Mail\Protocol\AbstractProtocol

this comes after SMTP server sends an error:

*Message submission rate for this client has exceeded the configured limit*

since this is thrown when destructor is called i am not able to catch it in my script. Any suggestion how to catch this, in my script.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to do with Zend Framework 2 or any other library. The message from the mail service which you consuming is pretty clear: **you're exceeding the rate limit**.

Anyway, you have several options;

- Never send lot of e-mails in a single while / for loop since you don't have a cool paid e-mail service which doesn't apply any rate limit to your account. (Paid or not almost every service like yours applies rate limits to prevent abusing. This is normal.)
- Add a `try {} catch() {}` block in your script and when you exceed the limit, just stop, wait for a while and try again.
- You may consider writing a cronjob and a CLI script to send X emails per minute.
- Implementing a [message queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue) an sending emails by consuming that queue (X emails at a time) would be better if you need to send thousands of emails.
- Ask your mail service provider to increase limits.
- Change your mail service provider if rates are still not enough.